# How to return articles if count is > 0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display only tags if have articles. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
  $tags = ATags::with('articles')->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id) {
      $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id)->
    })->limit(8)
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc(function($tag) {
        return  $tag->articles->count();
  });
```

Comment: I don't know PHP (rather python), but can't you write a `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
ATags::with('articles')->has('articles')->....
```

It will exclude tags which do not have any articles.